# Describe a random graph algebraically

Tags: recreational-mathematics, random-graphs

I'm not fluent in mathematics, but I'm wondering if it's possible to extract algebraic functions from random graphs like the following graph:

[image: pic]

Comment: Without any values at the axes it is impossible. If the values at the axes are known, you can define a linear stepwise function.

Comment: @callculus42 Yes, I have the numbers, on the X axis, they are a sequence of 1, 2, 3, 4 ... n, and on the Y axis, they are angles starting from 0 and going up to 360.

Comment: O.K. It is still a stepwise linear function. Or maybe you are only interested in the value where x are integers? Then the function would not be defined for non-integer x-values. Nevertheless the y-values are needed.

Comment: @callculus42 I want a function for each graph, that when given a value of X, returns the value of Y, is this possible?

Comment: Yes. But it must not be a function like $\sin(x), e^x,x^4, etc. $. At the first glance it does not seem that the values are the result of such functions. So you define a function for every x-value, i.e. $f(x)=\begin{cases} 5, x=1 \\ 3.6, x=2\\  2.2, x=3 \\ \textrm{undefined}, \textrm{elsewhere} \end{cases}$

Comment: Got it, thanks, sir!

Comment: You're welcome.